# How to open a process from terminal without becoming child process?

Tags: gnome-terminal

If I execute the following command in `LXTerminal`:

```
gnome-terminal &
```

`gnome-terminal` gets opened. But as soon as I close the `LXTerminal`, `gnome-terminal` will be closed as well because it's a child process. Is there any way to open the second process independently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible to start a process without it being the child. When you execute an external command, under the hood the shell calls `fork()` followed by `execvp()`. You can prevent it from getting killed when the parent shell dies.

One way is to use `nohup`:

```
nohup gnome-terminal &
```

Another option if you are using `bash` is to `disown` the process:

```
gnome-terminal & disown
```

Comment: `nohup` didn't seem to work for me but `disown` did.

Answer (score -1):

Yes just try to open this as follow.

```
$ sudo gnome-terminal &
```

So that both the terminals are available to you for work.
But remember not to close the Parent terminal, as it will close the child terinal.

I is possible with nohup.

```
$ nohup gnome-terminal &
$ exit
```

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question and even added an unnecessary `sudo`.

Comment: It is not possible to open child process independently. You are asking to kill the parent process, how can a child process will survive Meysam.

Comment: "It is not possible to open child process independently". Are you definitely sure it's not possible?

Comment: Yes i am definitely sure as per my knowledge. You can use that terminal but can not close that terminal.

Comment: @Meysam - *all* processes are children, with the exception of `init`.

Comment: Yes. please try with nohup command. May be it is possible. About init, it is a process that runs background. You can not kill init, unless you want to shut down your machine.

Comment: Go through this link http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/nohup-execute-commands-after-you-exit-from-a-shell-prompt.html It is possible, but about init, all processes are children with the exception of init as Jordanm said.